# Encoding, conversão bytes - strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, byte

Eu estou com um problema, estive a pesquisar mas todas a soluções que encontro não resultam. O problema é que estou a aceder a uma página (.txt) e não consigo converte-la de *bytes* para *string*, para conseguir trabalhar os dados (ex: `page.split("\n")`)

```
import urllib.request

def open_url(url):

   data = urllib.request.urlopen(url);
   page = data.read()
   return page

def Main():

   url = "http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt"
   page = open_url(url)

   print(page)

Main()
```

Até aqui tudo bem, a página é retornada e impressa em *bytes*, o que eu gostaria é agora de converte-la para *string*, já tentei:

```
print(page.decode('utf-8'))
```

Mas dá erro:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 289664: invalid start byte

Todas as outras soluções que vi são equivalentes à essa, podem mudar um bocado a sintaxe mas creio que fazem o mesmo, ex: `page.decode(encoding='UTF-8')`, o erro que dá é o mesmo descrito a acima.

Gostava de saber uma maneira de contornar isso e transformar isso em *string* 'formatável'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o código funcionou normalmente aqui, mas você pode tentar dar o print assim:

```
print(str(page, 'iso-8859-1'))
```

Aqui funcionou das duas formas.